# How to get C++ DLL created in rad studio to b used in C#

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++, c++builder

I need to use a 3rd party code/dll in my .Net service. I did some research. But I can't find any direct answer for this. Mostly are recommending to port the code into VS C++ .net using a wrapper class. At the same time since there are VCL-headers used which has no replacements in VS C++. Can someone guide me on this please?

The VCL files in use are : Classes.hpp, Sockets.hpp and, ExtCtrls.hpp

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you understand, that a service runs in a non-interactive session. If your library uses visual components from the VCL (e.g. ExtCtrls), then this doesn't sound right. You cannot use a library that uses a GUI from a service.

Comment: Its just using TTimer from ExtCtrls for processor. No GUI involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DLL written in C++Builder works just fine in C# *provided* that the DLL exports flat C-style functions that use basic interop-safe data types and calling conventions that are portable across multiple compilers. Or the DLL implements a COM object (since COM has a standardized ABI).  This is no different than writing any DLL that can be used in multiple languages including Delphi, VB, Java, Perl, PHP, etc.

You can't use VCL headers directly in the DLL's public interface, since VCL is not portable to non-Delphi/C++Builder compilers. But you can hide the VCL code behind an abstraction layer that is portable.